# Ошибка conflict tags при генерации кода из WSDL

Tags: golang, soap, wsdl

Есть две структуры

```golang
type AddPatient struct {
 XMLName xml.Name `xml:"http://teri.org/ AddPatient"`
}

type Patient struct {
 XMLName xml.Name `xml:"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Service.Data.Dto PatientDto"`
}
```

Для запроса к SOAP API использую именно ее.
Получаю такую ошибку

```
xml: name "patient" in tag of AddPatient.Patient conflicts with name "PatientDto" in *Patient.XMLName
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить этот конфликт.

Comment: В этом коде ошибки нет. Кладите более полную версию.

Comment: код всего этого генерируя с помощью.  
 https://github.com/hooklift/gowsdl.  Вот схема http://r42-rc.zdrav.netrika.ru/EMK3/PixService.svc?singleWsdl

Comment: После генерации получаем следующие.  https://pastebin.com/NbJxfq9S

Comment: Ваш генератор с приколами. Добавляет `XMLName` и тут же использует другое в структурах. [Вон](https://github.com/hooklift/gowsdl/issues/94) сколько людей жалуются.

Comment: да, читал... но не понимаю как можно это по другому реализовать.   Убил на это уже кучу времени.

Comment: Не работал с WSDL, так что могу предложить либо писать структуры самому, либо брать и руками править всё, что нагадил генератор.

Comment: Да, сейчас это и делаю, я тоже раньше не работал с WSDL так что туго идет.